# is one service enough for 70 statefulset/deployments pods?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have this doubt, will it be capable for handling a million request ?

Are we need service-per-pod?

Please anyone elaborate, how to handle this?

[image: Attached a image of service map]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by "a million request"? per second? per day?

Comment: Million request per second !

Comment: Then I recommend editing your question to clarify that.

Comment: A million requests per second, in a sustained way, is a **VERY** big traffic, really. Very few websites in the world have such traffic. Are you sure that's your real traffic?